# Check Finder Activity

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder

Is there any way I can check (programatically) if finder is busy e.g. copying files? I don't want to check it at file level; I just want to know in general if finder is busy copying.

I think it's not possible, but it is always worth giving it a shot here :)

Comment: I have tested it, but I don't see any specific processes popping up in the activity monitor.

Comment: Why do you need to know?  It should be possible to do other stuff while a copy goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Apple does not provide any method to retrieve this kind of information.
However, there are some 'dirty' ways that might work, for example using AppleScript.

The following script detects wether the 'copy window' by Finder is active or not:
(Quickly written and not thoroughly tested, but seems to be working great.)

```
set thestatus to "not copying"
tell application "System Events"
    set theList to get the title of every window of process "Finder"
    repeat with theItem in theList
        if theItem contains "Copy" then
            set thestatus to "copying"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
thestatus
```

Finally use `NSAppleScript` to run this AppleScript from Objective-C

```
NSString *theScript = @"set theStatus to \"not copying\"\n"
"tell application \"System Events\"\n"
"set theList to get the title of every window of process \"Finder\"\n"
"repeat with theItem in theList\n"
"if theItem contains \"Copy\" then\n"
"set theStatus to \"copying\"\n"
"end if\n"
"end repeat\n"
"end tell\n"
"theStatus";

NSDictionary *errorInfo = nil;
NSAppleScript *run = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:theScript];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *theDescriptor = [run executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];

if ([[theDescriptor stringValue] isEqualTo:@"copying"]) {
    NSLog(@"Finder is copying");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Finder is not copying");
}
```

Comment: This would work on a system with English as default language. Any hint on how to do this in a language-agnostic way?